# Larynx feeling a bit tense when hitting a high note?

Tags: pitch

When I hit a high note or sing in my head voice, I feel my larynx/Adams apple raised up and my larynx moving/vibrating.
I find it easier to hit high notes and to sing in head voice like this.

Is that normal?

How is the larynx/Adam's apple supposed to feel when in head voice or hitting a high note?

Comment: Your larynx shouldn't feel anything. Are you taking lessons?  It sounds to me like you are not fully supported up  there.  In my experience when one sings high it should not be forced or sound falsetto-ish, it should not be completely in the head, but in both the head and chest.

Answer (score 2):

You'll quickly find that vocal pedagogy is anything but clear and very highly debated as to what is considered "proper" or even healthy. The larynx can raise when singing in more contemporary styles, or create a tilt which causes an almost raised feeling in order to further adduct the vocal folds.

I would look into a vowel modification chart to help negate any sort of difficulty you're finding to the best of your ability. Record yourself singing, even if you're just singing for fun, and LISTEN TO IT! The acoustics in your head create a different perception of sound from what is actually being projected. If it sounds yell-y, it probably is! If you find your voice getting tired or numb and talking becomes labored, stop. Your body knows it's limits when it comes to the voice more than you do.

And to echo what others are sending, get yourself a coach! They are the ones who will be able to help you for certain, anything you read here may not be applicable to your situation because we don't know your voice.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd turn my comment into an answer:

Your larynx shouldn't feel anything. Are you taking lessons? It sounds to me like you are not fully supported up there. In my experience when one sings high it should not be forced or sound falsetto-ish, it should not be completely in the head, but in both the head and chest.

Answer (score 1):

Without hearing you I can tell you that if your larynx (Adam's apple) is raising, that already means you have tension in your throat.
Your adam's apple shouldn't raise if you sing higher, it should remain in a neutral positions.

As to how it should feel, If you start in a lower (but comfortable range) the notes should vibrate your chest , as you hit mix, the notes should vibrate your face, as you hit head voice, the notes should vibrate higher in your head.

I echo ggcg's question about voice lessons. Are you taking any , if not you should be taking them because it's easy to screw your voice up!